# Several groups of conflicts of interest -- conflicts of interests?

Tags: grammatical-number, compound-words

I am proofing a report on a survey concerning different groups of people working in journals. The following sentence has come up: "On the other hand, transparency about conflicts of interests, communication about the types of submissions handled by journals and the listing of journals in common repositories are rated as important quality criteria." Should I change "interests" to "interest"?

Comment: Yes, interest will do. Otherwise, you might as well write **transparencies** about conflicts of interests.

Comment: One can see your principal's logic, but the plural 'conflicts of interest' is far more common and does not preclude (nor, IMO, hint against) more than one such occasion arising. This involves at least notionally the distributive singular (cf 'points of law', 'men of war' [though the ships {female, of course} may have seen action in more than one war], 'women of stature' etc). // Note that 'conflict of interests' is a known, though rarer, singular-form variant.

Comment: It should be singular for the same reason *communication* is. (Also, a serial comma before your final *and* would greatly improve readability.)

Answer (score -1):

In the sentence you provided, "interests" is the correct word to use. The sentence is referring to conflicts of interests, which is a plural noun. In this context, "interests" refers to the different interests that individuals or groups may have that could potentially influence or bias their work.

The word "interest" is a singular noun that refers to a specific topic or activity that someone is interested in or involved in. For example, you might say "I have a particular interest in astronomy" to indicate that you are interested in studying the stars and planets. In the sentence you provided, "interest" would not be the correct word to use because it is not referring to a specific interest that someone has, but rather to conflicts of interests, which are multiple interests that could potentially conflict with one another.